# Change scope values in the view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm learning AngularJS and I have a question.

Here is my code:

HTML (view):

```
...
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="student in students">
        <td ng-class="{'student-highlight' : isStudent}">
            <input  type="checkbox"
                    ng-model="student.option"
                    ng-change="isStudent = checkStudent(student)" />
        </td>
 ...
<button type="button" ng-click="submit()">SUBMIT</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.checkStudent = function(student) {
    if(some_logic)
        return true; // It returns true for now
    else
        return false;
};

$scope.submit = function() {
    // I want to change isStudent in the view to false
};
```

So when a user change input box, it returns true so the cell is highlighted by the CSS class 'student-highlight'.  I want to change the value 'isStudent' in the view after the user hit the button 'submit'.

To do that, I used $$childHead in the controller:

```
for(var cs = $scope.$$childHead; cs; cs = cs.$$nextSibling) {
    if(cs.isStudent)
        cs.isStudent = false;
}
```

but I don't like what I did here - it's not pretty.  I think I could use $scope.$emit() or $scope.$broadcast(), but I don't know how.

Please help me out!!

Comment: Is isStudent a variable on your scope?

Comment: It's a child scope in the view

Comment: So in the controller, no.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but may be you add to scope `$scope.highlight = true;` Then in `ng-class="{'student-highlight' : isStudent && highlight}"` and then in `ng-click="highlight = false; submit()"`. This is of corse a concept only you have to optimize it by putting everything in place.

Comment: @SergeyRomanov Yes that's the exactly I did before the second solution (the above code).  And I thought it's not pretty as well.

Comment: @JaredReeves Then I need isStudent values as the same number of students.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you might want to take a look at Angularjs form validation. 
First you define the student-highlight under input.ng-dirty.
Then to clear the student-highlight, you can call $scope.form.$setPristine() in submit() to reset the form.

Comment: Do you think I can trigger the method checkStudent() using $scope.$broadcast()?

Comment: Why do you need to broadcast?

Comment: Because I want to trigger the method checkStudent()

Comment: Isn't checkStudent() triggered on-change?

Comment: Yes it does, but is there any way just to trigger the method from the controller side?

Comment: In that case, what is the event that will trigger checkStudent()?

Comment: So, after a user hit the submit button, the method checkStudent() is supposed to return 'false' so that the value isStudent set to false, but it doesn't.  I just want to know I can change the value isStudent or not from the controller side.

Comment: On second thought, I realised you just want to reset all isStudent to false using the CheckStudent(). If this is what you wanted, I guess it is achievable with $broadcast.

Comment: On the ng-repeat tag, you add a controller. That means all repeated element will have the same controller. Then you define checkStudent() in the controller, enclose with $scope.$on('event',function) to listen for the triggering event. Within the parent controller where you have the submit() function, you add a $rootScope.$broadcast('event') to trigger the event.

Answer (score 1):

A way to do this is to have a `bools = {}` object in your controller. Then, your view and your controller can simply access `bools.isStudent` for the current value. This gets even better when you migrate to the preferred `Controller As` syntax.

As an aside, you should never use any $$ property as they are private. From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05):

> $ Prefix Naming Convention
>
> You can create your own services, and in fact we will do exactly that in step 11. As a naming convention, Angular's built-in services, Scope methods and a few other Angular APIs have a $ prefix in front of the name.
>
> The $ prefix is there to namespace Angular-provided services. To prevent collisions it's best to avoid naming your services and models anything that begins with a $.
>
> If you inspect a Scope, you may also notice some properties that begin with $$. These properties are considered private, and should not be accessed or modified.

Comment: Also, you should never have a need for $broadcast or $emit. If you want to use those, you should be looking at directives and services.

Comment: I see. It takes a little more memory then. Thanks!

Comment: Angular is one of those quick to start, hard to master languages. There are many samples out there. Welcome to the language, and good luck on your journey.